# Playing sound with a picaxe

Tags: audio, speakers, picaxe

Is there any way to use a PICAXE  (08M2, to be precise) to play a small sound file (Not beeps and buzzes, but actual sound), perhaps loaded from an i2c EEPROM chip? I'm thinking something similar to the ThinkGeek EvilTron: two or three seconds of decent quality, mono-speaker sound. If not, is there a small/inexpensive slave chip that can accomplish this? I'm not looking for something fancy or complex, just enough to amount to a homemade EvilTron. Thanks for any pointers.

Here's a link to aforementioned EvilTron, just so you know: [EvilTron](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/electronic/c427/)

(also note I'm fully intending on using speakers well below the PICAXE's current limits, so no need for an amplifier circuit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1) The 'easy' way**

Add this [RAMTRON FM25V02 32k x 8 IIC non volatile memory](http://www.ramtron.com/files/datasheets/FM25V02_ds.pdf)

---

You could use [Roman Black's BTC encoder](http://www.romanblack.com/BTc_alg.htm)  to convert WAV files to 1 bit serial files that the processor can output.

[User discussion](http://www.picbasic.co.uk/forum/archive/index.php/t-8113.html)

[Typical background paper to PCM & friends](http://www.see.ed.ac.uk/~s0571365/Files/Articles/Communication/Modulations/Digital%20coding%20of%20speech%20waveforms_PCM_DPCM%20and%20DM%20quantizers_Javant74.pdf) - 1974 - old enough that what was leading edge hardware iis now almost trivial.

[Roman Black inspired Circuit Cellar article for speech coding on an 89C4051](http://intranet.daiict.ac.in/~ranjan/esp2006/lab/speech_encode.pdf)

[Relevantish](http://www.piclist.com/techref/com/circuitcellar/www/http/pastissues/articles/richey110/text.htm)

**________________________________________________**

**(2)  It's doable with on chip resources, with effort.**

The [PICAXE 08M2](http://www.picaxe.com/Hardware/PICAXE-Chips/PICAXE-08M2-microcontroller/) has very limited memory capacity compared to what is needed for storing raw sounds files. [PICAXE manual here](http://www.picaxe.com/docs/picaxe_manual1.pdf) in stock at Digikey [$5.8=77/1](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/FM25V02-GTR/1140-1027-1-ND/2809833)

This will allow storage of 4 seconds of speech or similar quality sound at 8k samples x 8 bits per second - or a lot longer at lesser rates.

---

Recording speech and playing it back as bytes to an ADC is usually down at 8 kB/s x 8 bits/Byte = 64 kbps. You can get reasonable quality down to about 16 kbps with ADPCM and lower again with care. If you used say 1kB of the program memory for data storage that's 8 kbit so for 2 seconds = 4kbps and for 4 seconds = 2 kbps.

LPC will achieve this with ease - but a PICAxe will not like LPC decoding.

At 4 kbps you may be able to use say 2 bit ADPCM and get something approaching speech out.

Dinner time. Food for thought there. More later probably ...

Search for:   Roman Black speech PIC
 for about as good as you can probably do.

Failing that, an external IIC memory will allow you to do this easily.

[image]

---

(3) Complete speech recording and playback ICs are available.

["Chipcorder" / ISD / Nuvoton is one such](http://www.nuvoton.com/NuvotonMOSS/Community/ProductInfo.aspx?tp_GUID=828f9580-5cab-4e8d-80f5-66da2eba3610) and also [here](http://www.nuvoton.com/hq/enu/pages/default.aspx)

Comment: Great thanks! Ya I'm definitly loading the sounds from external EEPROM, so this gives me a good starting point for figuring out how to encode it.

Answer (score 1):

There might be libraries which can help you to play sounds, (basically a header file with the frequency in hertz for each note). You might want to consider doing this to save yourself the hassle of buying a new chip. [I have attached sample code albeit for the arduino below, it should be very easy to port over]

Otherwise you might want to consider investing in a SoundPAL. Though this was designed for the BASIC stamp, it is very easy to interface with and in the worst case scenario bitbanging always works :) You just have to send in the notes and it'll play it on the onboard buzzer. It also has a variety of tunes stored in the EEPROM that you can play.

[image: SoundPAL]

http://www.parallax.com/Store/Accessories/Sound/tabid/164/CategoryID/38/List/0/SortField/0/Level/a/ProductID/482/Default.aspx

```
// define the frequencies for each note
#define c 261
#define d 294
#define e 329
#define f 349
#define g 391
#define gS 415
#define a 440
#define aS 455
#define b 466
#define cH 523
#define cSH 554
#define dH 587
#define dSH 622
#define eH 659
#define fH 698
#define fSH 740
#define gH 784
#define gSH 830
#define aH 880
```

```
//this function will play each note, so you just call the fn beep for each note to be played
void beep (unsigned char speakerPin, int frequencyInHertz, long timeInMilliseconds)
{
   int x;    
    long delayAmount = (long)(1000000/frequencyInHertz);
    long loopTime = (long)((timeInMilliseconds*1000)/(delayAmount*2));
    for (x=0; x less than loopTime; x++){
        digitalWrite(speakerPin,HIGH);
        delayMicroseconds(delayAmount);
        digitalWrite(speakerPin,LOW);
        delayMicroseconds(delayAmount);
}
delay(20); //to separate the notes
}
```

PS: I wasn't able to copy the exact code here so if anyone can fix the *less than* to < please do so.